# Meteor don't run after update to 2.7.3 from 2.2 - AccountsTemplates Error

Tags: meteor

I remove useraccounts:core from my project to update at the last version of meteor and than add again useraccounts:core when I have update to 2.7.3, but now meteor don't run.

Like the title, there is this error in promise_server.js and AccountTemplates have you any suggestions ?

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
W20220812-16:05:04.937(2)? (STDERR) /home/----/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.12.0.7cv555.76nvp++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:218
W20220812-16:05:04.966(2)? (STDERR)       throw error;
W20220812-16:05:04.967(2)? (STDERR)       ^
W20220812-16:05:04.967(2)? (STDERR) 
W20220812-16:05:04.968(2)? (STDERR) Error: AccountsTemplates: You must add at least one account service!
W20220812-16:05:04.968(2)? (STDERR)     at AT._init (packages/useraccounts:core/lib/server.js:19:11)
W20220812-16:05:04.969(2)? (STDERR)     at packages/useraccounts:core/lib/server.js:183:21
W20220812-16:05:04.969(2)? (STDERR)     at Function.time (/home/----/Documenti/GitHub/prevenzionecantieri/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:273:30)
W20220812-16:05:04.970(2)? (STDERR)     at /home/----/Documenti/GitHub/prevenzionecantieri/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:415:15
W20220812-16:05:04.970(2)? (STDERR)     at /home/----/Documenti/GitHub/prevenzionecantieri/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:465:7
W20220812-16:05:04.971(2)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (/home/----/Documenti/GitHub/prevenzionecantieri/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:280:14)
W20220812-16:05:04.971(2)? (STDERR)     at /home/----/Documenti/GitHub/prevenzionecantieri/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:463:13
=> Exited with code: 1
```

Where is the problem ?

I have try with:

> meteor add brettle:accounts-add-service

but I have this error:

```
 => Errors while adding packages:             
                                              
While selecting package versions:
error: Conflict: Constraint accounts-base@1.2.0 is not satisfied by accounts-base 2.2.4.
Constraints on package "accounts-base":
* accounts-base@~2.2.3 <- top level
* accounts-base@2.1.0 <- useraccounts:core 1.16.2
* accounts-base@2.2.0 <- service-configuration 1.3.0 <- accounts-base 2.2.4 <- accounts-ui 1.4.2
* accounts-base@2.2.0 <- accounts-ui 1.4.2
* accounts-base@2.2.2 <- accounts-ui-unstyled 1.7.0 <- accounts-ui 1.4.2
* accounts-base@1.2.0 <- brettle:accounts-add-service 0.2.0
* accounts-base@1.2.0 <- brettle:accounts-multiple 0.0.8 <- brettle:accounts-add-service 0.2.0
```

---

---

I have solved:

1. Meteor reset
2. meteor add fetch
3. meteor add accounts-ui
4. meteor add service-configuration
5. meteor add accounts-password
6. meteor add accounts-ui

Now work, I have to restore the database locally but meteor run

Comment: If you inspect the error, it's actually telling you that you haven't added any account services to AccountsTemplates. Have you checked what may have changed in those packages?

Comment: I have try with: meteor add brettle:accounts-add-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad you solved the issue! Can you mark your question as Solved? So it's easier for people find it

Thanks